# Getting error when implementing Pageable Interface in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my sample code in which I am trying to fetch the find the latest product through pagable interface ,

```
try{
Repo product = repo.findByIdDateAndValueExists(data.getId, data.getDate, request).getContent().get(0);
}catch(Exception e){
  LOGGER.error("Failed :: something went wrong: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Here is my repositorycode

```
@Query(value = "{'ID': ?0, 'Date' : ?1 ,'value':{'$exists': true}}")
Page<Repo> findByIdDateAndValueExists(String Id ,String Date,Pageable pageable);
```

Now what is happening in some case I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
And its breaking the entire flow of code , can someone pls suggest the correct way to handle such exception in such case , Any sort of help is appreciated .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can first check the size of result and then try to retrieve an element. something like

```
List<Repo> resutl = addressRepository.findByIdDateAndValueExists().getContent();
if (!result.isEmpty() {
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Before working on the whatever the result you have got, first you need to check whether it is returning any data or not.

According to your code `findByIdDateAndValueExists()` metho `addressRepository` will return Page of entity i.e.,

```
Page<Repo> page = repo.findByIdDateAndValueExists(data.getId, data.getDate, request);
// it will give how many pages it has return
int totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
if(totalPages>=1){
 List<Repo> products = page.getContent();
        .
        .
        .
        .
}else{
// do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JPA Query indexing starts with 1 so use this syntax for your custom query

@Query(value = "{'ID': ?1, 'Date' : ?2 ,'value':{'$exists': true}}")
Page findByIdDateAndValueExists(String Id ,String Date,Pageable pageable);